# circleCI permission denied after updating build tools image version

Tags: circleci, pantheon

just inherited a drupal site using circleCI to deploy to Pantheon.

Am needing to update the php to version 8.1+

Build tools image was originally set to: quay.io/pantheon-public/build-tools-ci:7.4.x

Have updated it to: quay.io/pantheon-public/build-tools-ci:8.x-php8.1

This is an example of the config: https://github.com/pantheon-systems/example-drops-8-composer/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml

Am now getting the following error during configure_env_vars > Checkout Code portion of the build.

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/www’: Permission denied

exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is to specify version `2.1` instead of `2`:

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
....
```

Then you can remove the `version: 2` in the "workflows" section or leave it as is; it's not mandatory if the main version of your `config.yml` is `2.1`.

For troubleshooting purposes, could you add the following step just before the `checkout` one:

```
- run: pwd
```